# Is std::launder needed after std::uninitialized_default_construct

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++17, allocator, stdlaunder

I have a code similar to the following which uses an allocator to allocate raw memory, and then uses `std::uninitialized_default_construct_n` (or another function of the same family) to construct objects in it.

```
std::allocator<T> allocator;
T* buffer = allocator.allocate(n);
std::uninitialized_default_construct_n(buffer, n);
buffer = std::launder(buffer); // needed?
...
std::destroy_n(buffer, n);
allocator.deallocate(buffer, n);
```

Is it needed to use `std::launder` on the pointer after this, to inform the compiler that the pointer now points to `T` objects? Or do the construct functions do the same thing implicitly?

It is for a container class, where I want to avoid value-constructing (instead of default-constructing) objects that will later be copy-assigned into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `std::launder` may only be necessary in the allocator itself, not at the point where it's used.
Note the effect of `allocate`:

> `a.allocate(n)`
>
> *Result*: `XX​::​pointer`
> *Effects*: Memory is allocated for an array of `n` `T` and such an object is created but array elements are not constructed.
>
> [*Example 1*: When reusing storage denoted by some pointer value `p`, `launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(new (p) byte[n * sizeof(T)]))` can be used to implicitly create a suitable array object and obtain a pointer to it.
> — *end example*]

- [[allocator.requirements.general] `allocate`](https://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.requirements.general#itemdecl:16)

Furthermore, [`std::allocator::allocate`](https://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.members#lib:allocate,allocator)

> *Returns*: A pointer to the initial element of an array of `n` `T`.

Even though the lifetime of the array elements has not yet begun, the lifetime of the surrounding array has begun.
`std::uninitialized_default_construct_n` begins the lifetime of elements and does not end the lifetime of the surrounding array.
This means that the elements of the array can be reached normally using the returned `buffer` pointer, which can be used in limited ways ([[basic.life] p7](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#7)).

`std::launder` would only be necessary if you were given a pointer whose provenance does not lead back to a `T` object (or array thereof) at all.
Example 1 in the quote shows how someone who implements `allocate` could use `launder`.

Comment: Hmm. https://eel.is/c++draft/allocator.members#3 says the returned pointer "points to the first array element", which sounds impossible if the element lifetime hasn't started yet...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you can use pointers to objects outside their lifetime in limited ways https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#7 . As long as the storage for the elements of the array has been allocated,  you should be able to take their address, even if you cannot access them.